# How to add asp.net authorization cookie to header request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session-cookies, asp.net-authentication

Can somebody tell me how to add asp.net cookie authorization to a request header (via MVC3)?

Cookie:

```
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=8+WZPGAaKtgkIPfbBovP1ZRP2qQKE3u67ueltnzcoCPH0nN1tUHdtgUorjlweUvn+zTJhkFeRuMShCOrbyHR5Xi3DOL4HCspXuVEOsWIr4Ape+l5MYPiFsQ6Lnw8LstqNjceWW9EaV24eA0mVxq2xTG18h/INNKLB8cRUiEn9DI=; .ASPXAUTH=C64A69436A8FC4A6DF5BC222982030C3CCF9E43FBCE335A47173236B4BA4B1CE762CBE6C9E9FDBB035D46C8F36228A61117F22DD55CF787D5E23A728F68B49DDF1A5D70FF3D33C8D16B06FC81894201E86DF93754B6021C9031CB4FBC5236DED952FB7244CE3217B659325A0614763B2E123002E5291EE8D8CEA7B2D7441F3EBB8176A71CDD6FEF3E545CDF46858174451D38890861664A55AF681A36C0B7CF1
```

Snippet of actual request:

```
Accept: text/*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------KM7Ij5Ij5ei4gL6KM7ae0cH2Ef1ae0
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Host: localhost:82
Content-Length: 36874
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=8+WZPGAaKtgkIPfbBovP1ZRP2qQKE3u67ueltnzcoCPH0nN1tUHdtgUorjlweUvn+zTJhkFeRuMShCOrbyHR5Xi3DOL4HCspXuVEOsWIr4Ape+l5MYPiFsQ6Lnw8LstqNjceWW9EaV24eA0mVxq2xTG18h/INNKLB8cRUiEn9DI=; .ASPXAUTH=C64A69436A8FC4A6DF5BC222982030C3CCF9E43FBCE335A47173236B4BA4B1CE762CBE6C9E9FDBB035D46C8F36228A61117F22DD55CF787D5E23A728F68B49DDF1A5D70FF3D33C8D16B06FC81894201E86DF93754B6021C9031CB4FBC5236DED952FB7244CE3217B659325A0614763B2E123002E5291EE8D8CEA7B2D7441F3EBB8176A71CDD6FEF3E545CDF46858174451D38890861664A55AF681A36C0B7CF1

------------KM7Ij5Ij5ei4gL6KM7ae0cH2Ef1ae0
<more stuff here...>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.  Cookies are automatically provided on each request when the cookie is set.

You set the cookie using FormsAuthentication class.   Typically, this looks something like this:

```
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /*createPersistentCookie*/);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using a flash plugin (Uploadify) for multiple file upload and it's not sending in this info so my action never gets hit (for callback file processing).  I get a 302 redirect back to my account/signin action.  I just noticed that the cookie is missing from header using chrome but it's there for IE9.

Comment: @JaJ - Then that's a flash problem, and has nothing to do with MVC.  MVC only does things server side, it has no control over how things are sent to it.

Comment: I understand that ... thus my initial ask. I more or less wanted to reach out to the MVC3 community because that is my application type. I appreciate the insight.